# Fragment on two layout fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

my problem is put fragment component on two fragments in the same layout. It is a dialog fragment which covers the window with menu(1 fragment) and table(2 fragment). How can I do that ?

Comment: reframe your question with some code and better explanation.The information provided is very less to understand ur prob

Answer (score 0):

You could use relative layout to put fragment on the top of other fragments in the same layout.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: so, which way  or  which property can I show dialog fragment over layout with 2 fragments in relative layout ?